# Given a set of SQL queries, how do I list all the required tables and fields?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have about 400 separate SQL files, each with is own select into my database. I want to list the tables and columns from where they extract the information.

I was thinking to upload them to my testing database and then use some system table to get the metadata. Not sure if this would be the better approach.

Comment: Read the files is the best way.

Comment: You could use something like Python/bash to parse the .sql files and save the table names to some file and take a unique on that.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I would also create views with the corresponding sql and then use DBA_DEPENDENCIES to extract the used database objects.

Comment: what if the files have updates and inserts.  the only way to do this is to read the files -- should take less than four hours.

Comment: Then you can use functions or packages instead of views. It's allways better to use the pl/sql compiler of Oracle then to do it by hand...